# Trying to fetch item price using Selenium with Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to fetch price of 1 kg Onion from jiomart,

however I keep getting series of errors the final being following:

Warning (from warnings module): File "C:\Users\Chandor\Desktop\Quotation.py", line 9 options.headless = True # set headless mode to True to suppress the browser window DeprecationWarning: headless property is deprecated, instead use add_argument('--headless') or add_argument('--headless=new') Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Chandor\Desktop\Quotation.py", line 17, in pincode_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='areaPinCode']") AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

# set the driver path and start the browser
driver_path = "C:/chromedriver/chromedriver"
options = Options()
options.headless = True  # set headless mode to True to suppress the browser window
service = Service(executable_path=driver_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

# navigate to jiomart homepage
driver.get("https://www.jiomart.com/")

# locate the search bar and search for onion
pincode_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='areaPinCode']")
pincode_box.clear()
pincode_box.send_keys("RANDOM AREA PIN")
pincode_box.submit()
time.sleep(3) # wait for page to load

# locate the search bar and search for onion
search_bar = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='searchbar']")
search_bar.clear()
search_bar.send_keys("onion 1 kg")
search_bar.submit()
time.sleep(3) # wait for page to load

try:
# locate the product div and get the price
product = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-name='Onion 1 Kg']")
price = product.find_element_by_class_name("sp__dp").text
print(f"The price of Onion 1 Kg is {price}")
except:
print("The product was not found on JioMart")

# close the browser
driver.quit()
```

And here's the code I used using Beautifulsoup + requests

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Set the URL for the search query
pincode = "110006" # Replace with your desired pincode
url = f"https://www.jiomart.com/category/fruits-vegetables/onion-garlic-ginger/onion/490?location= 
{pincode}"

# Set the user agent header to avoid 403 Forbidden error
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"}

# Send a GET request to the URL and retrieve the HTML response
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

# Parse the HTML response using BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

# Find the product div for 1 kg onion on the page
product = soup.find('div', {'data-name': 'Onion 1 Kg'})

# Check if the product div exists and extract the price if it does
if product:
# Extract the price of the product
price = product.find('div', {'class': 'final-price'}).text.strip()

# Print the price of 1 kg onion
print("The price of 1 kg onion on JioMart for pincode", pincode, "is Rs.", price)
else:
# Handle the case where the product is not found
print("The product was not found on JioMart for pincode", pincode)
print(response.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it is possible, you should NOT be using selenium for something like that. Try using either something like beautifulsoup + requests, or use an all in one tool like scrapy.

You are essentially web-scraping (taking data from a website), and you don't need to open a whole browser instance for that. It would be a lot easier, faster, more efficient, and cooler to make it using web scraping. You will also learn a lot more about parsing data, and html structure.

Selenium is a tool for browser automation. For example taking a picture of a webpage, or placing an order on an item. Although those things can be done with webscraping as well, it's a lot of the time just easier to use browser automation.

Now if you are deadset on using Selenium for you project, first add `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By` you will need this. Then add this `elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until( EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "XPATH TO ELEMENT")) )` this is to make sure that the input box is loaded. Then do `search_bar  = driver.find_by(By.XPATH, '//input[@id="areaPinCode")]'`

Comment: Initially I tried with beautifulsoup + requests. In response content I get the HTML content but not able to figure out what I need to do to correct code. I have pasted the code after editing my earlier question. Please review and let me know

Comment: From my testing, it seems to be a problem with the link you're using. You need to use a different link that shows the info about the Onion. From my testing, it seems that the link you provided is not valid.